# Launch Image loads a blurry game image in background

Tags: ios, asset-catalog, launchimage

I created my game in iOS 7.1, iOS 8.1. I put deployment target to iOS 7.0. I use iOS 7.1, 8.1, 7.0.3 simulators. I have all the proper sizes for all launch images from iOS 6,7,8. Launch image works fine for iOS 7.1, 8.1. The launch image loads my image and a black background = how I made it. However, in iOS 7.0.3 the launch image loads my image and then a blurry background of my game at the same time instead of black background. The game loads normally after launch image. How do I get rid of the blurry game background in launch image and make it black like it's supposed to be according to the launch images I provided in Images.xcassets?

Answer (score 0):

Put your deployment target at 7.1. Now your app will never accidentally run on a 7.0.3 device and the issue will never arise. (And in the real world there are no users of any interest who are still using 7.0.3; whoever can upgrade to 7.1, did upgrade to 7.1.)

Comment: I put my deployment target at iOS 7.0. However, in Xcode 6.1, the lowest iOS simulator I can install is iOS 7.0.3. Do you know if there would be any changes in the game between iOS 7.0 and iOS 7.0.3 ? That's why I put iOS 7.0 as deployment target, so I can support 7.0.3 as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is, why would you want to? No one in the world who _can_ upgrade from 7.0.3 to 7.1 _hasn't_ upgraded to 7.1, so you don't _need_ to support 7.0.3. Problem solved.